# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libwep

Tags: c++, node.js, webp

I upgraded to OSX Mojave a while back and ever since, have not been able to get past this problem.

I'm trying to install ibm_db2 node module which needs to build on my system.

The full output:

```
❯ npm i ibm_db

> ibm_db@2.5.0 install /Users/<username>/temp/ibm_db_try/node_modules/ibm_db
> node installer/driverInstall.js

Downloading DB2 ODBC CLI Driver from https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/macos64_odbc_cli.tar.gz...

100.00% | 20080158 bytes downloaded out of 20080158 bytes.

****************************************
You are downloading a package which includes the Node.js module for IBM DB2/Informix.  The module is licensed under the Apache License 2.0. The package also includes IBM ODBC and CLI Driver from I
BM, which is automatically downloaded as the node module is installed on your system/device. The license agreement to the IBM ODBC and CLI Driver is available in undefined   Check for additional d
ependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the components of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their respective license agreements. If y
ou do not accept the terms of any license agreement(s), then delete the relevant component(s) from your device.
****************************************

Downloading and extraction of DB2 ODBC CLI Driver completed successfully ...

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/odbc_bindings/src/odbc.o

{ Error: Command failed: node-gyp configure build  --IS_DOWNLOADED=true --IBM_DB_HOME="$IBM_DB_HOME"
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libwep
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/c++
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /usr/local/lib/libwep: code signature in (/usr/local/lib/libwep) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at le
ast ad-hoc signed.
        /usr/local/lib/libwep: stat() failed with errno=1
make: *** [Release/obj.target/odbc_bindings/src/odbc.o] Abort trap: 6
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/<username>/.nvm/versions/node/v6.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/<username>/.nvm/versions/node/v6.14.2/bin/node" "/Users/<username>/.nvm/versions/node/v6.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configur
e" "build" "--IS_DOWNLOADED=true" "--IBM_DB_HOME=/Users/<username>/temp/ibm_db_try/node_modules/ibm_db/installer/clidriver"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/<username>/temp/ibm_db_try/node_modules/ibm_db
gyp ERR! node -v v6.14.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:199:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:351:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:509:12)
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'node-gyp configure build  --IS_DOWNLOADED=true --IBM_DB_HOME="$IBM_DB_HOME"' }
npm WARN ibm_db_try@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN ibm_db_try@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

I've posted this issue in a couple of places but no luck

- https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/issues/500
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/109182

Anyone have a suggestion for getting past this? I'm considering downgrading but that seems like a temporary and expensive fix.