# Code signature in (/usr/local/lib/libwep) not valid on MacOS 10.14.6

Tags: macos, rust

I'm trying to follow the [100 days of Rust, day 12](https://dev.to/0xbf/day11-write-web-app-with-actix-web-100dayofrust-1lkn) and fail with a simple [Actix](https://actix.rs/) web server. This is my code so far (copy & paste from the blog):

### Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "blog-comments-rust"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["stwissel <stw@linux.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
actix-web = "2.0.0"
actix-rt = "1.1.0"
```

### main.rs

```rust
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};

async fn index() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("hello world!")
}

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new().route("/", web::get().to(index)))
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8000")?
        .run()
        .await
}
```

When I run this with `cargo run` the compiler tries to compile the dependencies but fails on a number of modules:

- backtrace-sys v0.1.35
- brotli-sys v0.3.2

both with the same error:

```
cargo:warning=dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libwep
cargo:warning=  Referenced from: /usr/bin/cc
cargo:warning=  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
cargo:warning=  /usr/local/lib/libwep: code signature in (/usr/local/lib/libwep) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
cargo:warning=  /usr/local/lib/libwep: stat() failed with errno=1
signal: 6

--- stderr
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libwep
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/git
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/libwep: code signature in (/usr/local/lib/libwep) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
    /usr/local/lib/libwep: stat() failed with errno=1
```

I believe this is a macOS issue rather than a Rust issue. I'm using macOS 10.14.6. My `libwep` parameters:

- 403,776 Bytes (406 KB on disk)
- created/modified 27 Jan 2017 07:40

```
ls -la libwep
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  403776 Jan 27  2017 libwep
```

[Full error log](https://gist.github.com/Stwissel/f3deb7a25179835774a51c2b272f3fc2).

What can I do to get my code compiling?

Comment: See also [dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libwep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55603445/155423); [CoreData model compiler fails because of libwep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29535743/155423)

Comment: It sounds like `libwep` is one of those "security" tools installed by companies on employees computers and that it hasn't been properly updated.

Comment: I think you're right.  It's injected into everything.  See [this](https://ftiff.wordpress.com/2016/04/01/triton-ap-endpoint-on-os-x/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out @Shepmaster and @trojanfoe were right. (Besides my code was full of syntax crap). The culprit is [ForcePoint DLP](https://www.websense.com/content/support/library/endpoint/v19/ep_upgrade/dlp_deployment.aspx). Unsigned libs is a bummer for "security". I have a ticket open with corpIt, see what they come back with.

The solution for now, is in the middle of ftiff's article [Triton AP-Endpoint on OSX](https://ftiff.wordpress.com/2016/04/01/triton-ap-endpoint-on-os-x/) @trojanfoe pointed me to:

```sh
sudo wepsvc –stop
```

if I could get away with it, I would rather `sudo wepsvc –uninstall`, but we need to keep [Central Services](https://www.redbubble.com/i/poster/Central-Services-Inspired-by-Brazil-by-WonkyRobot/27478398.LVTDI) happy.